# Navigation drawer from top - Android

Tags: android, android-navigation

I am trying to implement navigation drawer in my app. I know it can be made on the left and right side as well. But is it possible to implement it in such a way that it will slide in from the Top or bottom?

Thanks!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official reference for DrawerLayout to use "Bottom" or "Top" Gravity 
look at here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer%28int%29

but you can try this also, It may hlp you

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: Working @SP Sumit +1 Upvot For you